# MySQL Query Browser Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm using an old MySQL Query Browser which isn't a problem except for this one bit of code in my script that I cannot fix. I'll post the bit below along with the error.

```
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pets` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `petsaves`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `petsaves`;
CREATE TABLE `petsaves` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `characterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `petid1` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `petid2` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `petid3` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Error:

> 24086 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `pets` ENABLE KEYS*/;
>
> ```
>   --
>   -- Definition of table \`petsaves\`
>   -' at line 843
> ```

UPDATE***
If I remove this large dump of data into the tables pets everything works.

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pets` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `pets` (`petid`,`name`,`level`,`closeness`,`fullness`) VALUES
 (1,'White Bunny',1,0,50),
 (2,'Kino',7,100,72),
 (3,'Ger <3',4,12,60),
 (4,'Panda',15,2153,20),
 (5,'Sara',16,2213,82),
 (6,'Maya <3',2,1,98),
 (7,'Pink Bunny',1,0,100),
 (8,'White Tiger',1,0,88),
 (9,'Tiger',1,0,46),
 (10,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (11,'Penguin',1,0,56),
 (12,'Aimar',2,2,97),
 (13,'White',5,16,15),
 (14,'Baby Tiger',4,7,67),
 (15,'White Tiger',1,0,50),
 (16,'White Tiger',1,0,46),
 (17,'Snowman',1,0,56),
 (18,'Baby Tiger',13,1100,97),
 (19,'Sun Wu Kong',2,2,40),
 (20,'Elvis',5,15,90),
 (21,'White Tiger',3,3,6),
 (22,'Pink Bunny',1,0,100),
 (23,'Kino',1,0,96),
 (25,'Baby Robo',1,0,90),
 (26,'Pink Bunny',12,800,98),
 (27,'Black Kitty',1,0,86),
 (28,'Snowman',3,3,76),
 (29,'Koopa Jr',18,4414,15),
 (30,'Monkey',1,0,100),
 (31,'Husky',6,89,66),
 (32,'Husky',1,0,92),
 (34,'Baby Robo',1,0,93),
 (35,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (36,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (37,'Pikachu',3,5,15),
 (38,'White Bunny',2,2,90),
 (40,'Baby Robo',10,400,99),
 (41,'Rudolph',1,0,100),
 (42,'Rudolph',1,0,100),
 (43,'Grey',4,7,60),
 (44,'White Bunny',1,0,58),
 (45,'Monkey',1,0,100),
 (46,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,50),
 (47,'Kino',1,0,98),
 (48,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (49,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (50,'Panda',1,0,92),
 (51,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (52,'Pink Bunny',1,0,100),
 (53,'Allmighty',1,0,48),
 (55,'Baby Robo',3,4,44),
 (56,'White Tiger',1,0,7),
 (57,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (58,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (59,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (60,'White Bunny',1,0,80),
 (61,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (62,'BuNnY',2,2,15),
 (63,'BuNnY',10,403,94),
 (64,'Jr. Reaper',2,2,90),
 (65,'Dino Girl',3,4,40),
 (66,'Faint',2,2,15),
 (67,'Brown Puppy',1,0,37),
 (68,'Pink Bunny',1,0,14),
 (69,'PhagTard<3',2,2,38),
 (70,'Mini Yeti',1,0,70),
 (71,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,58),
 (72,'Monkey',1,0,92),
 (73,'iBlackyJr',1,0,70),
 (74,'White Tiger',1,0,90),
 (75,'Brown Puppy',1,0,91),
 (76,'Burt',2,1,70),
 (78,'Baby Dragon',1,0,73),
 (79,'Baby Tiger',13,1100,67),
 (80,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (82,'Baby Dragon',8,115,85),
 (83,'White Bunny',7,87,15),
 (84,'Husky',1,0,100),
 (85,'Tooth Fairy',2,1,100),
 (86,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (87,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,84),
 (89,'Baby Dragon',1,0,88),
 (91,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (92,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (93,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (94,'Husky',1,0,80),
 (95,'Husky',1,0,100),
 (96,'Kinky',1,0,96),
 (97,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (98,'Penguin',3,3,70),
 (99,'Golden Pig',5,21,15),
 (101,'Baby Tiger',10,400,15),
 (102,'Baby Dragon',12,701,61),
 (103,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (104,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (105,'Snowman',1,0,13),
 (106,'Baby Tiger',1,0,12),
 (107,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,13),
 (108,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (109,'Penguin',2,1,15),
 (110,'Golden Pig',3,5,15),
 (111,'Rudolph',4,7,15),
 (113,'Baby Dragon',13,1105,15),
 (114,'Bunneary',4,9,60),
 (115,'Brown Puppy',2,2,91),
 (116,'Mr.Husky',4,7,76),
 (117,'Husky',1,0,15),
 (118,'Sparky',16,2409,85),
 (119,'Husky',1,0,100),
 (120,'Baby Tiger',3,4,58),
 (122,'Baby Dragon',1,0,70),
 (123,'Mini Yeti',1,0,79),
 (124,'Mini Yeti',7,99,88),
 (125,'Cha-Cha',11,512,85),
 (126,'Mini Kargo',1,0,28),
 (127,'Husky',9,400,52),
 (128,'Mini Kargo',3,5,58),
 (129,'Japan',3,7,82),
 (130,'Baby Tiger',1,0,34),
 (131,'White Tiger',1,0,68),
 (132,'Baby Tiger',16,2400,70),
 (133,'White Bunny',1,0,94),
 (134,'White Bunny',2,1,100),
 (135,'White Tiger',3,3,80),
 (136,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (137,'Kino',12,800,100),
 (138,'White Tiger',2,1,15),
 (140,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,15),
 (141,'Baby Robo',0,0,97),
 (142,'Tony Tony',1,0,80),
 (143,'Monkey D',7,102,62),
 (144,'Panda',2,2,84),
 (145,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (146,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (147,'LittleBoy',2,2,32),
 (148,'White Bunny',1,0,54),
 (149,'Panda',1,0,96),
 (150,'Panda',1,0,100),
 (151,'Reshiram',16,2327,64),
 (152,'Penguin',2,1,76),
 (153,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,24),
 (154,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,15),
 (155,'White Tiger',1,0,68),
 (156,'Penguin',4,6,90),
 (157,'Snowman',2,1,72),
 (158,'Fan of Emil',9,200,90),
 (159,'Black Kitty',1,0,60),
 (160,'White Duck',13,900,100),
 (161,'Jr. Reaper',11,600,74),
 (162,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,96),
 (163,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,65),
 (164,'nooben',11,500,96),
 (165,'White Tiger',3,4,15),
 (166,'Husky',10,400,52),
 (167,'White Bunny',1,0,15),
 (168,'Penguin',1,0,50),
 (169,'Jr. Reaper',13,1100,36),
 (170,'Baby Tiger',1,0,70),
 (171,'Robo',1,0,100),
 (172,'Goldy',1,0,45),
 (173,'Suck my....',2,1,48),
 (174,'Black Kitty',1,0,13),
 (175,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (176,'Monkey',1,0,44),
 (177,'Pink Bunny',1,0,92),
 (178,'White Bunny',2,2,15),
 (179,'Baby Tiger',2,1,72),
 (180,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (181,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (182,'Baby Tiger',3,5,70),
 (183,'Black Kitty',1,0,100),
 (184,'White Tiger',5,14,96),
 (185,'Jr. Reaper',19,5525,15),
 (186,'Brown Puppy',1,0,70),
 (187,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,100),
 (188,'??? ??',1,0,100),
 (189,'Porcupine',1,0,100),
 (190,'Brown Kitty',15,1700,92),
 (191,'Kino',15,2489,76),
 (192,'Brown Puppy',1,0,82),
 (193,'whale',1,0,84),
 (194,'Turkey',1,0,100),
 (195,'Turkey',1,0,100),
 (196,'Turkey',1,0,100),
 (197,'Turkey',1,0,100),
 (199,'Baby Robo',1,0,80),
 (200,'Pink Bunny',16,2301,64),
 (201,'Kino',12,805,98),
 (202,'Black Kitty',1,0,98),
 (203,'Kino',10,302,92),
 (205,'Baby Dragon',1,0,6),
 (206,'Husky',1,0,74),
 (207,'Jr. Reaper',7,100,88),
 (208,'Monkey',4,10,88),
 (209,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,24),
 (210,'White Bunny',13,1101,96),
 (212,'Baby Dragon',3,3,85),
 (213,'[Kae]',13,1108,49),
 (214,'Brown Puppy',1,0,85),
 (216,'Star Jr.',15,2130,96),
 (217,'White Tiger',1,0,76),
 (218,'Sun Wu Kong',5,15,78),
 (219,'Baby Tiger',2,2,70),
 (221,'Dubu',15,1858,55),
 (222,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,90),
 (223,'Husky',1,0,16),
 (224,'Pupa',5,28,96),
 (225,'boothang',1,0,80),
 (226,'Kino',1,0,78),
 (228,'Baby Dragon',15,1800,15),
 (230,'Baby Robo',15,1900,100),
 (231,'Pink Bunny',1,0,76),
 (232,'White Bunny',1,0,34),
 (233,'Mini Yeti',1,0,58),
 (234,'Baby Tiger',5,30,88),
 (235,'Kino',3,3,100),
 (236,'Rudolph',1,0,48),
 (238,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (239,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (240,'Baby Dragon',4,9,97),
 (241,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,98),
 (242,'Husky',3,3,88),
 (243,'Penguin',9,245,84),
 (244,'Monkey',1,0,100),
 (245,'Penguin',6,52,68),
 (246,'Sushi',1,0,100),
 (247,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (248,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (249,'Husky',1,0,72),
 (250,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (251,'Penguin',1,0,54),
 (252,'Black Kitty',1,0,78),
 (253,'Black Dragon',1,0,100),
 (254,'Blue Dragon',1,0,100),
 (255,'Red Dragon',1,0,100),
 (256,'Snowman',1,0,58),
 (257,'White Tiger',2,2,15),
 (258,'Kino',1,0,16),
 (260,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (261,'Mini Yeti',2,2,13),
 (262,'Sun Wu Kong',13,1100,98),
 (263,'GrrrImScary',15,1704,67),
 (264,'Penguin',2,2,50),
 (265,'Kino',9,200,100),
 (266,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,15),
 (267,'POKE <3',17,3303,61),
 (269,'Midnight',16,2200,48),
 (270,'Baby Tiger',1,1,73),
 (271,'Lumuu',13,1100,76),
 (272,'Brown Kitty',1,0,90),
 (273,'Mini Yeti',2,2,82),
 (274,'Snowman',1,0,82),
 (275,'Baby Tiger',19,5500,100),
 (276,'Bomb',7,101,84),
 (277,'Baby Tiger',1,0,43),
 (279,'Baby Robo',1,0,66),
 (280,'Baby Tiger',13,1100,70),
 (281,'White Tiger',1,0,36),
 (282,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (283,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (285,'Robo',1,0,100),
 (286,'Baby Robo',0,0,77),
 (287,'MushyMush',1,0,58),
 (288,'Baby Tiger',1,0,34),
 (289,'White Tiger',5,27,70),
 (290,'Jr. Reaper',5,20,15),
 (291,'White Duck',2,1,15),
 (292,'Snowman',2,1,11),
 (293,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (294,'Mini Kargo',7,100,88),
 (295,'Shoe.',19,5502,68),
 (296,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,88),
 (297,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (298,'Kino',1,0,84),
 (300,'Yuri',15,2303,46),
 (302,'Baby Dragon',17,3405,88),
 (303,'Penguin',9,270,64),
 (304,'Baby Tiger',1,0,19),
 (305,'Rawrz',14,1602,88),
 (307,'Baby Robo',6,68,54),
 (308,'Baby Tiger',11,600,49),
 (309,'Sushi',4,12,50),
 (310,'White Bunny',22,8812,100),
 (311,'Baby Tiger',1,1,67),
 (312,'White Tiger',5,21,98),
 (313,'Panda',5,24,15),
 (315,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (316,'Penguin',1,0,66),
 (317,'Brown Puppy',1,0,34),
 (318,'Mini Yeti',1,0,7),
 (320,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (321,'Nick Jr',16,2210,94),
 (322,'Rudolph',1,0,80),
 (323,'Sushi',1,0,88),
 (324,'Mini Yeti',1,0,100),
 (325,'Golden Pig',1,0,50),
 (326,'Husky',4,8,42),
 (327,'Baby Tiger',1,0,91),
 (328,'White Duck',1,0,49),
 (329,'DaBoy',16,2400,70),
 (330,'Pink Bean',6,55,67),
 (331,'Black Bunny',1,0,100),
 (332,'Crys.Rudolph',6,42,94),
 (333,'Jr. Reaper',3,3,94),
 (334,'Penguin',1,0,76),
 (335,'DaLeetDaLeet',5,17,56),
 (336,'Kino',1,0,94),
 (337,'Star',12,800,15),
 (339,'Baby Dragon',1,0,97),
 (340,'Kino',1,0,86),
 (341,'Crazy',10,305,70),
 (342,'White Tiger',3,5,70),
 (343,'Baby Tiger',2,2,55),
 (344,'Lucy',1,0,66),
 (345,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (346,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,100),
 (347,'White Bunny',1,0,76),
 (348,'Kino',1,0,96),
 (349,'Cutie<3',17,3300,15),
 (351,'Baby Dragon',1,0,70),
 (352,'Kino',1,0,84),
 (353,'Panda',4,10,84),
 (354,'Jr. Balrog',7,101,95),
 (355,'Panda',1,0,44),
 (356,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,100),
 (357,'White Tiger',3,4,90),
 (358,'Monkey',18,3709,80),
 (359,'Awesomo',2,1,30),
 (360,'Keox',1,0,11),
 (361,'White Bunny',2,1,62),
 (362,'Husky',1,0,10),
 (363,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (364,'Brown Puppy',1,0,100),
 (365,'Querx',1,0,11),
 (367,'BooDragon',19,5536,79),
 (368,'White Bunny',13,905,70),
 (370,'Baby Robo',1,0,100),
 (371,'Kino',14,1321,86),
 (372,'Stubby',9,200,15),
 (373,'Penguin',2,1,40),
 (374,'White Tiger',1,0,48),
 (375,'Icy<3',4,13,52),
 (376,'Swagsurfin',9,200,58),
 (377,'Bryan',1,0,40),
 (378,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (379,'Husky',1,0,84),
 (380,'Robot',1,0,66),
 (381,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (382,'Monkey',2,1,64),
 (383,'Pink Bunny',9,200,96),
 (384,'Panda',1,0,100),
 (385,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,82),
 (386,'Kino',7,100,62),
 (387,'Rage',10,300,90),
 (388,'Swagsurfin',17,3009,97),
 (389,'Brown Kitty',11,500,100),
 (390,'White Tiger',1,0,13),
 (391,'BigThing',16,2200,70),
 (392,'White Tiger',1,0,78),
 (393,'White Tiger',1,0,48),
 (394,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (395,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (397,'PetLatin',1,0,10),
 (398,'PONCHO',2,2,96),
 (399,'Baby Tiger',1,0,52),
 (400,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,15),
 (401,'Brown Puppy',1,0,15),
 (402,'Grim Reaper',1,1,100),
 (404,'Baby Dragon',13,1200,97),
 (405,'Penguin',1,0,30),
 (406,'Baby Tiger',1,0,73),
 (407,'Monkey',2,3,70),
 (408,'Pink Bean',5,23,97),
 (409,'White Tiger',1,0,52),
 (410,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (411,'Kino',6,47,96),
 (412,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (413,'White Bunny',1,0,78),
 (414,'Kino',1,0,66),
 (416,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (417,'Baby Tiger',1,0,58),
 (418,'Doggie (:',0,0,55),
 (419,'CreamPie',16,2201,76),
 (420,'Sun Wu Kong',11,600,15),
 (421,'IrSexy',15,1715,70),
 (422,'Kino',1,0,68),
 (424,'Baby Robo',20,6761,58),
 (425,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,15),
 (427,'Baby Dragon',18,4002,73),
 (429,'Baby Dragon',18,4400,91),
 (430,'Penguin',1,0,54),
 (431,'Svampbob',16,2700,64),
 (433,'Baby Dragon',9,200,94),
 (434,'Penguin',1,0,26),
 (435,'NickJr',16,2200,15),
 (437,'ZackJr',1,0,100),
 (438,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (439,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (440,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (441,'Baby Tiger',3,4,67),
 (442,'White Bunny',1,0,62),
 (443,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,65),
 (444,'Husky',1,0,98),
 (445,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (446,'Penguin',1,0,13),
 (447,'White Duck',1,0,100),
 (448,'Baby Tiger',1,0,15),
 (449,'Jr. Yami',1,0,15),
 (450,'Baby Tiger',1,0,70),
 (451,'Kino',1,0,98),
 (452,'Sun Wu Kong',1,1,98),
 (453,'Sargon',2,2,82),
 (454,'Brown Puppy',1,0,76),
 (455,'Mini Kargo',1,0,100),
 (456,'Mini Kargo',4,8,70),
 (457,'Baby Tiger',7,100,15),
 (458,'White Tiger',4,10,82),
 (459,'AndCookies',16,2211,100),
 (460,'Monkey',16,2303,76),
 (461,'Hosea(:',1,0,68),
 (462,'White Tiger',1,0,66),
 (463,'Honda',15,1801,84),
 (465,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (466,'Baby Robo',3,3,96),
 (468,'Baby Dragon',6,59,97),
 (470,'Alpha.Jr',14,1307,95),
 (471,'Husky',13,1100,100),
 (472,'White Duck',3,5,70),
 (473,'Penguin',3,3,15),
 (474,'Kino',7,100,80),
 (475,'Husky',1,0,100),
 (476,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (478,'Lil BadAzz',13,900,50),
 (479,'Baby Tiger',1,0,64),
 (481,'Jr.singer',16,2402,80),
 (482,'Sun Wu Kong',4,12,96),
 (483,'Baby Tiger',1,0,49),
 (484,'P!nkeh',5,15,66),
 (485,'White Tiger',1,0,98),
 (487,'Baby Robo',1,0,99),
 (488,'Brown Kitty',1,0,94),
 (489,'Evo\'s Pet',2,4,88),
 (490,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,46),
 (491,'Snowman',1,0,98),
 (492,'Baby Tiger',7,100,100),
 (493,'White Duck',1,0,55),
 (494,'Sun Wu Kong',5,15,90),
 (495,'Kino',2,1,72),
 (496,'Baby Tiger',1,0,42),
 (497,'Panda',9,201,72),
 (498,'Kino',1,1,86),
 (499,'White Bunny',10,300,72),
 (500,'Baby Tiger',2,1,55),
 (501,'Baby Tiger',1,0,82),
 (502,'Kino',1,0,15),
 (503,'White Duck',1,0,76),
 (504,'Baby Tiger',17,3400,70),
 (505,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (506,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (507,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (508,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (509,'White Duck',1,0,100),
 (511,'Baby Robo',3,5,98),
 (512,'Gever',10,409,100),
 (513,'Penguin',1,1,92),
 (514,'Pink Bunny',1,0,58),
 (515,'Panda',11,529,100),
 (516,'iPod',1,0,28),
 (517,'Kino',1,0,90),
 (518,'Xia0Gu0',12,700,50),
 (519,'Husky',1,0,54),
 (521,'Baby Robo',1,0,88),
 (522,'Sara',2,1,62),
 (523,'Kino',11,509,96),
 (524,'Penguin',1,0,52),
 (525,'Husky',1,0,70),
 (527,'Baby Dragon',15,2001,94),
 (528,'White Duck',1,0,15),
 (529,'Baby Tiger',14,1600,25),
 (530,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (531,'White Duck',7,100,31),
 (532,'Kino',1,0,74),
 (533,'Auzure',8,135,50),
 (534,'Baby Tiger',2,2,94),
 (535,'White Tiger',4,9,82),
 (536,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (537,'Fatass',16,2232,100),
 (538,'White Duck',1,0,52),
 (539,'Sun Wu Kong',13,1212,86),
 (540,'xDaniel',8,176,100),
 (541,'Panda',13,1113,72),
 (542,'Snowman',11,500,100),
 (543,'Baby Tiger',1,0,28),
 (544,'White Tiger',1,0,76),
 (545,'Snowman',1,0,54),
 (546,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,90),
 (547,'-sun',12,800,92),
 (548,'Shifu',1,0,96),
 (549,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,100),
 (550,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (551,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (552,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,68),
 (553,'Lune',2,2,92),
 (554,'Baby Tiger',7,100,94),
 (555,'Black Kitty',1,0,100),
 (556,'Husky',3,4,98),
 (558,'Xavier',13,1100,91),
 (559,'White Duck',1,0,100),
 (560,'Piplup.',1,0,98),
 (561,'MySexy',30,30000,90),
 (562,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (563,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (564,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (565,'White Tiger',1,0,15),
 (566,'Sven',1,0,42),
 (567,'Sushi',1,0,98),
 (568,'Ruben',13,1017,82),
 (569,'Baby Tiger',1,0,22),
 (570,'Baby Tiger',1,0,91),
 (571,'Baby Tiger',4,6,91),
 (572,'Crys.Rudolph',1,0,100),
 (573,'Crys.Rudolph',1,0,100),
 (574,'Crys.Rudolph',1,0,100),
 (575,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,86),
 (576,'Baby Tiger',1,0,31),
 (577,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,98),
 (578,'Husky',1,0,86),
 (579,'Baby Tiger',1,0,43),
 (580,'White Tiger',1,0,22),
 (581,'Monkey',1,0,88),
 (582,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,76),
 (584,'Nature',15,2202,15),
 (585,'Baby Tiger',1,0,58),
 (586,'Dino Boy',5,14,96),
 (587,'Black Kitty',1,0,84),
 (588,'Kino',2,2,15),
 (590,'Contamination',10,400,70),
 (591,'Baby Tiger',11,500,85),
 (593,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (594,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (595,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (596,'Panda',10,400,64),
 (597,'Jr. Reaper',6,37,98),
 (598,'Panda',1,0,92),
 (599,'Panda',1,0,15),
 (600,'White Tiger',1,0,72),
 (601,'White Tiger',1,0,74),
 (602,'Black Kitty',1,0,66),
 (603,'Kino',1,0,10),
 (604,'Panda',1,0,48),
 (605,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (606,'Baby Tiger',6,59,55),
 (607,'Penguin',2,1,88),
 (608,'White Tiger',5,19,98),
 (609,'Kino',7,100,80),
 (610,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,6),
 (611,'Mini Yeti',1,0,15),
 (613,'Baby Dragon',13,1103,70),
 (614,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (616,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (617,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (618,'Kino',8,109,96),
 (619,'Sushi',7,100,82),
 (620,'Panda',1,0,15),
 (621,'Golden Pig',23,10206,70),
 (622,'Stein',15,1643,94),
 (623,'Ruben<3',11,500,94),
 (624,'Sara<3',15,1900,64),
 (625,'White Bunny',1,0,76),
 (626,'Baby Tiger',1,0,34),
 (627,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,64),
 (628,'Snowman',9,200,10),
 (629,'Baby Tiger',4,10,49),
 (631,'Dragon',15,2000,70),
 (632,'Kino',1,0,78),
 (634,'Baby Dragon',18,3601,82),
 (635,'Shiver',9,200,15),
 (637,'Baby Robo',11,501,83),
 (638,'Baby Tiger',1,0,97),
 (639,'Baby Tiger',1,0,94),
 (640,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (641,'Kino',16,2409,76),
 (642,'Twix',16,2608,61),
 (643,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,86),
 (644,'Aidsto',15,1800,62),
 (645,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (646,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (647,'Golden Pig',1,0,100),
 (648,'Aria',1,0,15),
 (649,'Golden Pig',1,0,100),
 (650,'Ketchup',1,0,96),
 (651,'Baby Tiger',1,0,67),
 (652,'Baby Tiger',3,4,100),
 (654,'Baby Robo',21,7725,79),
 (656,'Baby Dragon',1,0,10),
 (658,'Baby Dragon',1,0,97),
 (659,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (660,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (661,'Mini Kargo',1,0,82),
 (662,'Penguin',1,0,72),
 (663,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,82),
 (664,'Black Kitty',9,401,58),
 (665,'Husky',1,0,94),
 (667,'Corey',11,605,88),
 (669,'Baby Dragon',9,207,16),
 (670,'Husky',1,0,96),
 (671,'Cee-Loo',2,1,24),
 (672,'Moonstar~',4,13,64),
 (673,'Lilly',1,0,90),
 (674,'Baby Tiger',1,0,43),
 (675,'Black Kitty',1,0,100),
 (676,'Penguin',2,1,86),
 (678,'Baby Dragon',13,1100,82),
 (679,'Roar',7,69,82),
 (680,'Kino',4,12,15),
 (681,'Baby Tiger',1,1,67),
 (682,'Mini Yeti',1,0,91),
 (684,'Baby Dragon',10,404,40),
 (686,'Baby Dragon',1,0,94),
 (687,'White Bunny',3,4,88),
 (688,'Mini Kargo',13,1200,85),
 (689,'Angel<3',4,10,38),
 (690,'Mini Yeti',1,0,94),
 (691,'FuckHead',1,0,92),
 (693,'Yami',1,0,19),
 (694,'Jr. Zackie',1,0,15),
 (696,'Baby Robo',16,2204,100),
 (697,'Mini Yeti',1,0,100),
 (698,'White Tiger',1,0,94),
 (699,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (700,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (701,'White Bunny',3,3,15),
 (702,'Frosty',9,200,56),
 (703,'mikki',4,22,70),
 (704,'Kino',2,2,50),
 (705,'Baby Tiger',7,100,10),
 (706,'Devil </3',18,3705,75),
 (707,'iRsexy',6,56,58),
 (708,'Panda',1,0,52),
 (709,'Panda',1,0,100),
 (710,'White Tiger',3,3,80),
 (711,'Cookies',5,26,15),
 (713,'Tora Jr.',2,1,79),
 (714,'Baby Tiger',1,0,91),
 (715,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (716,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (717,'Sara',1,0,94),
 (718,'Ruben',13,1117,90),
 (719,'Robot',1,0,100),
 (721,'Baby Robo',15,2102,90),
 (722,'Orange',16,2440,88),
 (723,'Mini Yeti',3,4,85),
 (725,'Baby Robo',1,0,69),
 (726,'Kino',9,204,98),
 (727,'COCO',8,116,67),
 (728,'Kino',14,1311,88),
 (729,'Equal',2,1,79),
 (730,'Baby Tiger',1,0,94),
 (731,'Baby Tiger',2,2,85),
 (732,'White Tiger',5,17,80),
 (733,'White Tiger',1,0,10),
 (734,'White Bunny',4,6,96),
 (735,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (736,'Baby Tiger',7,100,58),
 (738,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (739,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (740,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (741,'Kino',1,0,90),
 (742,'Turkey',9,200,98),
 (743,'Chris',19,5198,85),
 (744,'Pink Bean',1,0,100),
 (745,'Ohai',1,0,15),
 (746,'Baby Tiger',7,100,37),
 (748,'Labour',15,2062,27),
 (750,'Baby Dragon',8,109,100),
 (752,'Baby Robo',6,36,99),
 (753,'Robo',1,0,100),
 (754,'White Bunny',1,0,36),
 (755,'Husky',1,0,100),
 (756,'Penguin',7,81,50),
 (757,'Kino',10,400,68),
 (759,'SexyStuff',1,0,60),
 (760,'doggydoggy',9,203,55),
 (762,'Baby Dragon',23,10927,15),
 (764,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (766,'Baby Dragon',14,1401,100),
 (767,'Angel<3',17,2904,96),
 (768,'Pico',12,717,15),
 (769,'Baby Tiger',12,807,91),
 (770,'Penguin',3,3,74),
 (771,'White Tiger',1,0,15),
 (773,'Baby Dragon',19,4502,91),
 (774,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (776,'Baby Dragon',18,3903,97),
 (777,'Penguin',1,0,50),
 (778,'Baby Tiger',1,0,76),
 (779,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (781,'Baby Robo',2,5,38),
 (782,'Kino',20,6306,15),
 (783,'White Bunny',1,0,15),
 (784,'Jr. Reaper',6,35,15),
 (785,'Baby Tiger',4,11,91),
 (786,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,76),
 (787,'Turkey',4,25,15),
 (788,'Husky',14,1410,80),
 (789,'MosDef',25,15500,15),
 (790,'Penguin',3,3,15),
 (791,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (792,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (793,'Kino',1,0,100),
 (794,'White Bunny',7,100,100),
 (795,'Wizzam',6,36,76),
 (796,'Kino',2,2,15),
 (797,'<333',13,1100,90),
 (798,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,92),
 (799,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,65),
 (800,'Jr. Reaper',11,600,88),
 (801,'Mushi`BABY!',15,2004,7),
 (803,'Baby Robo',1,0,93),
 (804,'yami',1,0,82),
 (805,'Biancax3',1,0,97),
 (806,'Kitten',9,200,85),
 (807,'Brown Puppy',1,0,100),
 (808,'Ambulante',14,1300,61),
 (809,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (810,'White Tiger',1,0,88),
 (812,'Baby Dragon',1,0,85),
 (813,'White Bunny',3,5,100),
 (814,'Baby Tiger',4,8,76),
 (815,'Kino',2,1,54),
 (816,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (817,'Kino',3,3,78),
 (818,'Orange tiger',1,0,100),
 (819,'Snowman',1,0,100),
 (820,'Skunk',1,0,90),
 (821,'White Duck',1,0,88),
 (822,'Sun Wu Kong',2,2,80),
 (823,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,52),
 (824,'Jr. Reaper',7,101,15),
 (825,'Baby Tiger',1,0,94),
 (826,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (827,'Monkey',1,0,15),
 (828,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (830,'Baby Robo',1,0,88),
 (831,'Rudolph',1,0,94),
 (832,'Husky',2,2,92),
 (834,'Baby Dragon',1,0,64),
 (835,'Pink Bunny',1,0,98),
 (836,'Kino',0,0,94),
 (838,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (839,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (840,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (841,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (843,'Baby Robo',1,0,83),
 (844,'Baby Tiger',4,12,79),
 (845,'biggie',1,0,96),
 (846,'Penguin',3,5,78),
 (847,'Golden Pig',1,0,35),
 (848,'Husky',2,1,52),
 (850,'Baby Robo',1,0,100),
 (851,'Baby Tiger',1,0,52),
 (852,'Baby Tiger',4,8,97),
 (853,'BoyBoy',13,1110,15),
 (854,'Husky',1,0,98),
 (855,'White Tiger',4,9,28),
 (856,'Robo',1,0,100),
 (857,'Kino',1,0,15),
 (859,'Baby Dragon',14,1303,100),
 (860,'Husky',6,31,72),
 (861,'Husky',1,0,70),
 (862,'Sun Wu Kong',13,1101,46),
 (863,'Sexy<3',13,1101,96),
 (864,'Jr. Balrog',5,19,75),
 (865,'Pink Bunny',1,0,74),
 (867,'Baby Dragon',4,7,15),
 (868,'Kino',8,139,48),
 (869,'Kino',1,0,66),
 (870,'DEFAME LUDA.',1,0,49),
 (871,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (872,'Derp',1,0,100),
 (873,'Brown Kitty',1,0,100),
 (874,'Mini Kargo',5,20,25),
 (875,'Snowman',5,16,94),
 (876,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (877,'Ryan<3',5,15,64),
 (879,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (880,'Jr. Death',1,0,15),
 (881,'Kino',5,31,15),
 (882,'Robo',1,0,100),
 (883,'Mini Yeti',1,0,100),
 (884,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (885,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (886,'iRsexy',15,2300,94),
 (887,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,100),
 (888,'Panda',1,0,15),
 (889,'Mini Yeti',2,2,100),
 (890,'White Bunny',1,0,92),
 (892,'Baby Robo',1,0,98),
 (893,'Jr. Reaper',1,0,76),
 (895,'Baby Robo',3,5,83),
 (896,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (897,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,68),
 (898,'Baby Tiger',9,200,97),
 (899,'Jr. Reaper',16,2200,74),
 (900,'Baby Tiger',1,0,43),
 (901,'Penguin',1,0,100),
 (902,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,96),
 (903,'Robot',1,0,100),
 (904,'Steve',2,2,58),
 (905,'Boner',1,0,66),
 (906,'ASSHAIRS',16,2200,15),
 (907,'Brown Puppy',1,0,100),
 (908,'Cookies <3',1,0,64),
 (909,'Baby Tiger',1,0,100),
 (910,'Mini Yeti',2,2,28),
 (911,'Sun Wu Kong',1,0,100),
 (912,'Baby Tiger',1,0,15),
 (913,'White Tiger',1,0,100),
 (914,'Trippy',2,4,66),
 (915,'Jr. Death',1,0,74),
 (916,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (917,'Kino',10,312,100),
 (918,'Dino Boy',1,0,12),
 (919,'Panda',5,27,92),
 (920,'Brown Kitty',1,0,100),
 (922,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (923,'Dragon',1,0,100),
 (924,'Baby Dragon',1,0,100),
 (925,'Dino Girl',1,0,72),
 (926,'Dino Girl',1,0,100),
 (927,'Dino Girl',1,0,100),
 (928,'Dino Boy',2,1,15),
 (929,'Jr. Balrog',2,2,65),
 (931,'Baby Dragon',1,0,9),
 (932,'Nico.<3',13,1113,82),
 (933,'Angel.<3',2,1,98),
 (934,'White Bunny',1,0,100),
 (935,'Jr. Balrog',1,0,100),
 (937,'Baby Dragon',1,0,88),
 (938,'Kino',7,100,94),
 (939,'Baby Tiger',13,1100,100);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pets` ENABLE KEYS */
```

Comment: the error is not visible. Please select it and copy paste it here or type it.

Comment: The image is very hard to see. Please copy the error as text.

Comment: Are there any `DELIMITER` declarations above this point in the script?  For example, `DELIMITER ;;` or `DELIMITER $$` -- anything *other than* `DELIMITER ;`?

Answer (score 2):

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pets` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Remove the ; at the end

Comment: @TheRealBass Just tried, if I remove that semicolon it gives an error on the `DROP` statement. So the first error is gone.

Comment: Look at my edit, you're right its something with the previous inserting of data into the pet table.